# how to create child by user define in firebase database

Tags: java, android

I want to  make a child as a "user" but here some default value  coming.
a user is a child but below the user, some default value is coming which I don't want... I don't know to fix this. how?

[image]

```
 mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads").child("user");
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to write data to the database are you using .push() method with your insert query? 
This creates a random generated Id for the pushed value. Instead just use the .setValue(object) to insert your data.

Refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for read and write help.

Comment: sir i read  "Read and Write Data on Android"  but it's not helpful  for me...   sir ...from where the default value is coming

Comment: can u show me your method that writes the data to the database?